# How can I combine 2 observable that return success result event if one of them was failed?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to subscribe to two observables methods but one might get an error and the second may success.
But when I try to do it I get only error event if one of them return success

when I'm using combineLatest I get only error even if the first is success

```
 combineLatest(
    this.createTable1(),
      this.createTable2()
     ).pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(() => {
        alert('suceess');
      }, (error) => {
        alert('error');
      });
```

when I do like the following it works only if the second is failed, if the first is failed I didn't get an alert of success:

```
   this.createTable1().pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe( () => {
      alert('1suceess');
         this.createTable2().pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe( () => {
           alert('2suceess');
         }, () => {
           alert('error');
         });
      }, () => {
      alert('error');
    });
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is RxJS completes the stream once an error has been caught before you get the value for the other one, so you need to handle the errors in each stream and make them back into an observable.

```
combineLatest(
  this.createTable1().pipe(catchError(() => of('Errored'))),
  this.createTable2().pipe(catchError(() => of('Errored')))
).pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
 .subscribe(() => {
   alert('suceess');
 }, (error) => {
   alert('error');
 });
```

This should work. I didn't know this myself, I tested it in this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xzdtpn?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

You'll see if you comment out line 9, we never get to know about the later observable.

EDIT:
I am adding a different version in case you don't care to know if one of the observables failed:

```
merge(
  this.createTable1().pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY)),
  this.createTable2().pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY))
).pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
 .subscribe(() => {
   alert('suceess');
 }, (error) => {
   alert('error');
 });
```

Comment: It doesnt work if the first is failed, you get an error and I doesn't continue to the next one

Comment: Do you get the `alert('error')` or `alert('success')`?

Comment: I get alert('error') when the first observable is failed and nothing from the second one

Comment: If you are still getting alert error, you didn't add the `catchError` correctly to each observable, otherwise you would be catching it before the subscribe. Maybe you can share the code as you have it now?

Comment: ``` combineLatest(
      this.createTable1().pipe(catchError(() => {
       alert('error1');
        return EMPTY;
      })),
      this.createTable2().pipe(catchError(() => {
        alert('error1');
        return EMPTY;
      })),
    ).pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(() => {
        alert('suceess');
      }, (error) => {
        alert('error');
      });```

Comment: The problem is `combineLatest` will only trigger the subscribe when both observables emit a value, but you're using `EMPTY`, which doesn't emit anything. You need to send something down the observable, that's the reason I used `of('Something')`.

Comment: Also remember you can always use `merge` instead of `combineLatest`, in that case you CAN use `EMPTY` in the `catchError` like you were doing, and you'll still receive the value that didn't error.